# JavaScript const and let scoping syntax validity

Tags: javascript

Is the below valid JavaScript?

```
const x = 1;

if(x){
  const x = 2;
  console.log(x); // 2
}
console.log(x); // 1
```

As in, redefining `x` as a `const` (or `let`) within an inner block-scope?

Redefining as `var` isn't allowed, because this would be hoisted to the top scope and then conflict with original `x` declaration.

I think I'm correct here, right? Redefining in this way is allowed? Is this supported by all major JS engines?

Comment: Please refer to the MDN documentation (Block scoping) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Block_scoping

Comment: It's allowed but, in my case I have a linting rule to avoid this https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow

Comment: Well *allowed*... hoisting is *allowed* as well (as in none prevents you from doing it), yet still both are confusing and lead to errors/oversights on maintaining. Better to prevent both (shadowing and hoisting).

Comment: The hoisting mentioned here (var hoisted over a const) is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the block is valid because of [variable shadowing](https://medium.com/@shankar.bala96/javascript-hoisting-variable-shadowing-scope-and-closures-27ed946c8769).

The second time you declare `x`, it gets declared in an inner scope and it will shadow all the variables with the same name in the outer scopes.

This allows you to give the name you prefer to your variables, without worrying if an external library or somewhere above there was a variable with the same name.

For example, you can declare `let i` for an index several times. If you couldn't, you should declare `let i` just once and then use `i = ...` all the other times.

But, if in the future you will decide that you won't need `let i` in the outer scope, you could delete it without thinking too much about consequences, and `i = ...` will become a global variable.